# CreateDropdown List in Excel using C# which (list )is present in one column of excel sheet

Tags: c#

CreateDropdown List in  Excel using  C# which (list) is present in one column of excel sheet

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

Spire.XLS is designed for developers, enables to generate, write, edit and save Excel workbooks. Spire.XLS for .NET provides XlsRange class which contains DataValidation property to represent data validation for specified cell range. Three properties bool IsListFormula, String[] Value and bool IsSuppressDropDownArrow should be set to create a dropdown list. The value for the first property must be a String array so that you can initialize a String[] instance with a series of Unicode characters at first. Set the second property as true to form a list which saves initialized String array and the third property as true to present dropdown list arrow on the right of cell to indicate that a dropdown list is applied for this cell. [Download and install Spire.XLS for .NET](http://www.e-iceblue.com/Download/download-excel-for-net-now.html) and follow the code:

```
using System; 
using Spire.Xls;

namespace DropdownList  

{  
 class Program
 {  
     static void Main(string[] args)  
     { 
         Workbook workbook = new Workbook();    
         Worksheet sheet = workbook.Worksheets[0];  
         sheet.Range["A1"].Value = "blue";  
         sheet.Range["A2"].Value = "red";  
         sheet.Range["A3"].Value = "white";     
         CellRange range = workbook.Worksheets[0].Range["A1:A3"];  
         workbook.Worksheets[0].Range["C2"].DataValidation.DataRange = range;    
         workbook.SaveToFile("ExcelDropdownList.xlsx", ExcelVersion.Version2010);  
      }  
 }  
 }
```

There is a good tutorial [HERE](http://spreadsheets.about.com/od/datamanagementinexcel/qt/20071113_drpdwn.htm) on how to use excel drop downs

Comment: actually i didn't want to use 3rd party dlll i.e.

Comment: Check this - http://www.clear-lines.com/blog/post/Excel-In-Cell-DropDown-with-CSharp.aspx

Comment: above link code is not working if in list data is greater than 256 character that's why i'm trying for another procedure which was mention..